# How to get date ticks in a javaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, date

I have such a code in the C#:

```cs
public static decimal StringDateToDecimal(this string stringDate)
{
    var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("ru-Ru");
    var date = DateTime.Parse(stringDate, cultureInfo);
    var number = date.ToBinary();

    var unix = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    var diff = (date - unix).Ticks;
    return (decimal)diff;
}
```

For 01 march 2018 it returns 15198624000000000.
But code in the js:

```
var from = $input.split(".");
var d = new Date(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0]);
var dStart = new Date(1970, 1, 1);
var seconds = d.getTime();
var secondsStart = dStart.getTime();
var dateDifference = seconds - secondsStart;
```

For "01.03.2018" it returns 1517184000000

or

```
var ticks2 = ((d.getTime() * 10000) + 621355968000000000);
var ticks1 = ((dStart.getTime() * 10000) + 621355968000000000);

var difrent = ticks2 - ticks1;
```

What am I doing wrong in the js code?
I want to get the same value in the js

Comment: Ticks are not the same as seconds.

Comment: I can add the conversion to ticks but nothing changes

Comment: Are you trying to convert from one to the other, c# and js? Or just trying to implement the same function in both?

Comment: I want to get the same value in the js

Comment: Note that both a JavaScript Date and a .NET DateTime are accurate only to about 10-15ms. So getting the value of Ticks (down to 100ns) is kind of silly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- **JavaScript:** `Date.getTime()`: a number, representing the number of milliseconds since midnight January 1, 1970.
- **C#:** A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond, or 10 million ticks in a second.

So, `JavaScript ticks = (C# ticks / 10000)` and your code looks OK. You just need to account for the difference in whichever code (C# or JavaScript) you choose.

If you take (an unambiguous day-month date) in JavaScript *(e.g. 23 December 2018)*:

```js
var $input = "23.12.2018";
var from = $input.split(".");

var dNew = new Date(from[2], from[1]-1, from[0]);
//Note dStart has 0 as month because JavaScript dates start at 0 and end with 11
var dStart = new Date(1970, 0, 1);
var seconds = dNew.getTime();
var secondsStart = dStart.getTime();
var dateDifference = seconds - secondsStart;
// multiply by 10000 to reconcile to c#
console.log("===> " + dateDifference * 10000);
```

Both answers come to 15455232000000000 if you use `StringDateToDecimal("23 december 2018");` in your C# code.

I hope I'm getting the jist of what you are asking.

Comment: This is part of the answer. If I multiply the result by 10,000 then I get a number of the same order. But the values will still be different 15198624000000000 and 15171840000000000

Comment: Agreed - I've updated the answer, changing the instantiation of new Date() in the script and yielding the result in console.

Comment: @rajesh What was the context of your comment? Did you feel H's calculation was wrong? I mean, it would be difficult-to-impossible to fire them both off at the same time and receive the same value from both. This is more how to take one and create a date time in the other. There's almost certainly going to be a discrepancy between any two executions from different codebases.

Comment: The calculation is correct, just that the variables should probably be named milliseconds and millisecondsStart, since Date.getTime() returns the time value in milliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

The JavaScript [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) type's origin is the Unix epoch starting at midnight on 1 January 1970.

The .NET [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03ybds8y.aspx) type's origin is midnight on 1 January 0001.

And for ticks, from the [`DateTime.Ticks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) docs:

> A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond, or 10 million ticks in a second.

So with all of that in mind, your code can be reduced to this:

```
var d = new Date(2018, 3, 1); // Your date
var dStart = new Date(1970, 1, 1);
var dateDifference = ((d.getTime() - dStart.getTime()) * 10000);
console.log(dateDifference); // 15198588000000000
```